# Using import the right way?

Tags: python, importerror

In Python3.3 (bash, installes via macports) I do not understand the errors of the code at the end of this post. What do I do wrong? I know it is a basic question - I thought I already understood that...

```
>>> import matplotlib
[removed - should not disturb (s. comments)]
>>> import matplotlib as plt           # (*)
>>> plt.pyplot.plot([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pyplot'
>>> 
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot([1,2,3])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x10370d210>]
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: The first error: maplotlib vs. matplotlib.

Comment: Ok, this one is solved. I will edit the question and remove the `>>> maplotlib.pyplot.plot([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'maplotlib' is not defined` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spelling errors/typos.  you import matplotlib and reference maplotlib.  then it looks like you try and do attr access on a module to get a submodule.

to answer a question left in the comments, i will demonstrate with twisted (as i have it installed):

```
>>> import twisted
>>> twisted.web
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'web'
>>> import twisted.web
>>> twisted.web
<module 'twisted.web' from '/home/alex/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

In order to access a module, you need to import the module, even if it is part of another package.

Comment: 1st: Yeah, see comments above. 2nd: This one I do not understand. It is not fine to access a module and then access a submodule of this module in (*)?